# Argument list too long for UGE compute host

Tags: shell, environment-variables, sh, sungridengine

In my .profile (SUSE Linux with Korn shell) I have had the following code active for many years:-

```
case $0 in
-ksh|ksh)
    set -o ignoreeof
    set -a
    set -o vi
    PS1=$(print '\033[34m$(tput bold)ksh:$(hostname)->$(tput sgr0)\033[00m ')
    PS2="continue-> "
    PS3=": "
    PS4="$0.$LINENO+ "
    FCEDIT=/usr/bin/vi
    HISTFILE=~/.histories/${TTY}_$(hostname)_ksh_his
    HISTSIZE=500
    EDITOR=/bin/vi
    VISUAL=/bin/vi
    TERM=gnome
    set +a ;;
*) SHELL=${SHELL} ;;
```

But lately that PS1 entry has been causing some unexpected problems. When I source a file of ~3K environment variables and then try to get onto to a UGE compute host, the following error causes everything to break down:-

```
$ qrsh -V -j y -pe mt 1 -l "os_version=SUSE12.0,model=EMT3500,cpu_code=E5-2667v4" -P iheavy -now no
ksh: /usr/bin/tput: Argument list too long
ksh: /bin/hostname: Argument list too long
ksh: /usr/bin/tput: Argument list too long
ksh:->
```

If I request a CentOS system (os_version=CS7.0) I do not see the error--it is specific to SUSE. Also, if I eliminate the PS1 entry altogether, I can get onto a SUSE system without any errors. This is the simplest way to capture the bigger problem: when I issue a qsub for batch computing tasks, my .profile ends up partially initialized and jobs fail to launch.

I often change environments and shells, so color-coding my terminal prompt in a shell-specific and host/queue-specific way has always been helpful. I would rather not retire that PS1 entry just for one project that has such a long list of environment variable names.

I have done various searches and learned that increasing ulimit settings can sometimes help in situations like this; however, I tried that (increased stack size and number-of-open-files to their maximum) and the outcome did not change.

Is there a practical way to avoid this problem without removing the PS1 entry?

Comment: Despite the wording of the error message, it's the combined space used by the environment *and* the arguments that is too large. When that space is limited, even one argument can push the size over the limit when you have a large environment.

Comment: As @chepner noted this really has nothing to do with your PS1 var.  The OS kernel typically has a fixed maximum amount of space it supports (configured when the kernel is built) for the combination of the env vars and the arguments to the `execve` syscall. Three thousand env vars is excessive; although, strictly speaking it isn't the number of env vars but the combined space required for the var names and values that is the problem. You should find a more suitable mechanism for making some of that data available to whatever programs need it.

Comment: Note that none of the `PS*` variables need to be exported: they are only used by the shell, not any other program, and they almost always contain shell-specific escapes that aren't useful to different shells. Just make sure they are set in the appropriate shell configuration files, and they will be defined for the shells that need them, without having to inherit them.

Comment: The same goes for `FCEDIT`, `HISTFILE`, `HISTSIZE`, and I suspect a large number of your other 3000 environment variables.

Comment: By the way, `*) SHELL=${SHELL} ;;` does nothing useful at all. The variable is obviously already set to this value and the `case` statement does not require you to put in a default case.